# What does jQPlot's Axis option "scaleToHiddenSeries" do?

Tags: charts, jqplot

I've seen it being used in Pyramid Charts but can't figure out what it does and how to use it.
I've looked it up in the documentation - it's too curt.

"True to include hidden series when computing axes bounds and scaling."
How to supply those hidden series?
How to how make them hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://kkmcentr.ru/servis/dist/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html#Axis.scaleToHiddenSeries) - and as the option's name says - it specify if either or not you want to include hidden series when computing axes bounds and scaling.

**Edit - Explanation :**

Let's say you have 3 series in your data but you only want to display the two first ones (the third one is hidden). The **scaleToHiddenSeries** specify if either or not you want to include this third serie when computing bounds.

For example for serie 1, xaxis goes from 10 to 15; for serie 2 from 12 to 17; finally for serie 3 from 11 to 999.

If you set scaleToHiddenSeries to true when your third serie is hidden, the jqplot xaxis will go from 11 to 999. Conversely, if you set scaleToHiddenSeries to false, the jqplot xaxis will go from 10 to 17

Comment: It did not even occur to me to explicitly say that i have had RTFM before asking the question. But yes, i did and it did not make it any clearer